# Display date format while retrieving the value from database in MCV 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 $("#DateOfJoining").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

This is jquery coding for date .
But while retrieving the proper date format did not come.

Comment: post code how you are retrieving date???

Answer (score 0):

use this `dd/MM/yy` instead of this `dd/mm/yy`

`mm` it is a minute not month

[also read this article](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)